# Please consider reopening 'Tools for user stories' question

Tags: discussion

The question [Is there a tool for managing user stories?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/19226/is-there-a-tool-for-managing-user-stories) may be a little clumsily worded, but it's in essence a really important question to the UX community, particularly beginners.

I agree it could definitely use some rewording, perhaps to something like "What are some useful tools for capturing and understanding user stories?". And perhaps 'An ideal tool would..' could be changed to 'An ideal tool **may**' (since not every tool will do everything well).

Please consider editing + reopening.

Comment: This is probably no the place to ask for a question to be reopened, but I have provided an answer here as well as a comment in the original question.

Answer (score 0):

For tool recommendations on UXSE, the process for moderators is to migrate them to Software Recommendations so there would be no reason to re-open unless you are happy to consider changing the question to asking about the process that can be used to define and refine user stories (which can be supported by various tools).

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, just because the subject matter is relevant and useful to UX practitioners, that doesn't mean the question is a good fit for Stack Exchange.

The whole format of Stack Exchange is for a specific question to be asked based around a single problem that needs solving, and for people to provide **the** correct solution to that problem.

The whole UX.StackExchange site - and Stack Exchange as a whole - is a repository for problems that other people may also have at any point in the future but haven't been able to find the solution for.

"*How can I get X to do Y?*" is a question that will have a correct answer today, and that same answer will be correct in 5 years time. "*What is the best piece of software to design a UI?*" is a question that *may* have a subjective 'best' answer today, but in 1 years time there could be a totally new piece of software that does everything that one does, but much better. Or that other piece of software could have been discontinued. So the question will be out of date (assuming the subjective answer could even have been considered 'correct' in the first place).

Jeff Atwood (co-founder of Stack Exchange) wrote a blog post about these 'shopping request' questions way back in 2010. It is still relevant today: https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/11/23/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/